# Не видит php-cs-fixer?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Операционная система **Ubuntu 18.04**. Установил глобально `php-cs-fixer`([источник](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)):

```
$ composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

Находясь в папке проекта добавил в `$PATH`:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Делаю команду обновления:

```
$ sudo php-cs-fixer self-update
```

> sudo: php-cs-fixer: команда не найдена

Как сделать, чтобы работало?